# Adding background image in CSS using HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS, I'm trying to add Full Screen Background Image in CSS, but my code doesn't work. I've tried many tutorials as well. Here it's my code.

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Shirjeel\Desktop\Web-Development\site\CSS\practice.css">
<h1>Welcome to my First CSS page.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and  CSS file

```
body{
    background-image: url(""C:\Users\Shirjeel\Desktop\Web-Development\site\CSS\landscape.jpg"");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Why _double_ double quotes around the URL value?

Comment: I've also added single quotes around url value but it didn't work.

Comment: Check if the browser console reports any errors.

Comment: Your code has typo `background-image: url("C:\Users\Shirjeel\Desktop\Web-Development\site\CSS\landscape.jpg");` remove double quotes

Comment: I've removed double quotes but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a working example, you made one mistake & one bad practice:
- You used double """" for your background URL
- The CSS link is recommended to be in the head. You can put it in the body but place it add the end.

```css
body{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\Shirjeel\Desktop\Web-Development\site\CSS\landscape.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* DEMO, remove */ background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg");
  /* DEMO, remove */ color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS</title>
    <!-- comment out -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Shirjeel\Desktop\Web-Development\site\CSS\practice.css">-->
</head>
<body>
    
<h1>Welcome to my First CSS page.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your **double-quotes** in the URL you should remove them. Also,  you can use a relative path to get your image from your project path.

Answer (score 0):

```
style="background-image: url('img_shirjeel.jpg'); height: 100%; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;"
```

try this in that tag or body where you want the image. 
and do google first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your css file to the main folder (the same as the html file).
And create a div(container were background has to come) that contains your h1.
And you shouldn't use the full url you can just use foldername/imagname.jpg.
So this is how it should look.

Folder.

-html.html

-practice.css

-imagefolder
      --image.jpg

If you have this you can change the css link to :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice.css">
```

And then in body tag you creat a div with a class:

```
<div class="body">
  <h1>Welcome to my First CSS page.</h1>
</div>
```

If you have this you can give the body div a background image with in css:

```
.body{
  background-image: url(image/landscape.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 500px;
}
```